# Do randomized algorithms always give an approximate result? Why? Why not?

Tags: algorithm, approximation

I was wondering if they give approximate results all the time, I am unable to understand.

Comment: This cannot be answered in general. It depends how randomness is used in the algorithm. For example for some algorithms the result is exact, but the run-time may vary.

Comment: The short answer is no. Does the wikipedia age on randomized algorithms help? The second paragraph is especially relevant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm